# Java Servlet Questions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a few Questions regarding servlets:

- In Ruby on Rails you use the MVC-Architecture, how is it solved with servlets?
- What is the difference between a .jsp file and a servlet?
- If I want to create a model with a form, where would I put that form, into a servlet or into a jsp file, or somewhere entirely different?
- How do I change the URL's of my jsp files, because having an url like `example.com/example.jsp` for a .jsp file, and `example.com/example` for a servlet seems wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: difference between a .jsp file and a servlet - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097732/7218656

Answer (score 0):

In summary:

- Servlets are basically your Controllers in MVC architecture
- JSP files are your Views as it contains your HTML
- Since JSP files contains your HTML, forms should go to JSP. You could put forms into your Servlet if that's what you need.
- You could either render your JSP from your Servlet(s), or map your Servlet in `web.xml` so it catches every request, and then forward the request to the target page.

Given below is just an example from others:

In `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>YOUR_SERVLET</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then inside your Servlet

```
String includeJsp;

String query = req.getRequestURI();
if (query == null || query.isEmpty() || query.equals("/")) {
 // home - intro
 includeJsp = "/about-intro.jsp";
} else if (query.equals("/games.html")) {
 includeJsp = "/games.jsp";
} else {
  // TODO
}

// draw JSP
req.setAttribute("includeJspContent", "/pages"+includeJsp);
try {
 req.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").include(req, resp);
} catch (ServletException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Reference:

- http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/11/servlet-jsps-create-easy-dynamic-web.html
- https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServerPages.html